# Automatically switch between network profiles based on what Thunderbolt dock is connected on a Dell notebook

Tags: networking, network-manager, dell, ethernet, thunderbolt

I'm using a Dell Latitude notebook with Ubuntu 22 LTS. I have two Ethernet network profiles with static IPv4 configuration (setup using network-manager-gnome). One is my home-office network and one is for the office. I have a Thunderbolt-4 dock which provides Ethernet in each location.

How can I make NetworkManager switch between the two profiles automatically, depending on which Thunderbolt dock is connected?

##### What I've tried so far

I tried to specify the MAC address in the "Identity" tab (which sets `802-3-ethernet.mac-address`). This did not work as according to NetworkManager, both hubs/docks have the same MAC address.
**Edit:** This is because Dell's ["MAC Address pass through"](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ae/000143263/what-is-mac-address-pass-through) feature was enabled.

Comment: I have an XPS 15 from 2022 and I can't seem to fix this. I have a dock in my office which requires 802.1x authentication to sign onto the network. It's some StarTech USB-C dock. Then, I have a dock at home that is an OWC 14 port TB4 dock. I have MAC PAss Through set to disabled in the BIOS. And yet, in Kubuntu 22.04, I still have the same MAC address for both devices. It's frustrating because of the authentication required in the office which I then have to make sure to disable before I head home. Not sure if you or anyone else has any idea of what else to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of NetworkManager is to create separate connection profiles for every network device. This did not happen in this case because a Dell feature called "[MAC Address pass through](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ae/000143263/what-is-mac-address-pass-through)". It is enabled by default in the BIOS of some notebooks. If enabled, supported Ethernet peripherals always use the notebooks own MAC Address, which is why the device name stayed the same.

**Disabling "MAC Address Pass-Through" in the Dell notebook's BIOS will solve this issue.** On my notebook this option is found in the section "Pre-boot Behavior". After the change, NetworkManager will create separate profiles for the different docks which can be configured independently.